# Java SWT - Create a pure SWT Table with different color on even and odd rows

Tags: swt

I am very new to the SWT and I am trying to create a Java SWT table with different color on even and odd rows (ex: 1st row is red, second row is blue, third row is res, fourth row is blue ... ).

Since the rows on table can be deleted, inserted so if I manually set color by using a for loop I will have to run that loop again and again to set color every time there's something change in the table. And I don't want to use JFace, just pure Java SWT
Do you have some better solutions for this problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom drawn table items](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/index.html) .

By adding a listener for the `SWT.EraseItem` you can just draw the background and let the rest do the default implementation. Use the `item` field of the event to decide whether an even or odd row is to be drawn.

For example:

```java
table.addListener( SWT.EraseItem, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
    int index = table.indexOf( ( TableItem )event.item );
    if( index % 2 == 0 ) {
      Color oldBackground = event.gc.getBackground();
      event.gc.setBackground( event.display.getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_DARK_YELLOW ) );
      event.gc.fillRectangle( 0, event.y, table.getClientArea().width, event.height );
      event.gc.setBackground( oldBackground );
    }
  }
} );
```

Comment: @Mr.Herrmann : Here is the line below event.gc.fillRectangle( 0, event.y, table.getClientArea().width, event.height ); trying to fill a table row or the full table?? I am totally new to `SWT`. I tried the above but it set two items on one row and showed just a line in the desired color. In other words it did not fill the row.

Comment: @Stars12 the mentioned code fills a row with the current background color. If that doesn't work for you, I suggest to post a new question with a description of what you want to achieve and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you tried so far.